# How to Delete DataGridView Rows using RemoveAt?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

Im just new to vb.net and I need to delete some specific rows but

```
DataGridView.Rows(8).Visible = False
```

does not work I also tried using

```
DataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(8)
```

It deletes the row BUT the problem is when I try to perform this function again there's an erro that says index out of bounds

Please help Im really out of ideas in the moment

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the row at the **source** (datasource) of your grid not delete the datagridview row

Comment: if you delete a row in datasource of a datagridview then the row should be removed in the datagridview too

Comment: I mean I tried using this script 
    SELECT DISTINCT B.AccountGroup AS BU 
      FROM leads.dbo.oppAssignedAccount A
        INNER JOIN custo.dbo.cdbAccounts B ON A.AssignedAccountID = B.AccountID
        WHERE A.AccountID = 415
        AND ((A.AccountID = A.AssignedAccountID AND B.ValidTo > GETDATE()) 
    OR A.AccountID <> A.AssignedAccountID)  
   AND iif(len(B.AccountGroup.Value) = 'CB01',True,False)
  ORDER BY 1 but it did not work it always return an error syntax error near '='

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
  DataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index)
```

this is for Current Row

And you Can Change Index to remove Last Index

```
  DataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index - 1)
```

And you Can Change Index to remove Next Index

```
  DataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index + 1)
```